# How to set boolean field for annotation

Tags: spring, spring-boot, java-annotations

I am learning Spring annotation

```
public @interface Autowired {
    boolean required() default true;
}

public @interface Lazy {
    boolean value() default true;
}
```

here is what I have:

```
@Autowired(false) - wrong
@Autowired(required=false) - correct

@Lazy(false)  - correct
@Lazy(value = false) - correct
```

Why Autowired(false) is wrong and @Lazy(false)is correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is attribute named **`value`**, [then the name may be omitted, as in](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/annotations/basics.html):

```
public @interface Lazy {
    boolean value() default true;
}

@Lazy(false)
```

If there is no attribute named **`value`**, you can assign a value by specifying it explicitly:

```java
public @interface Autowired {
    boolean required() default true;
}

@Autowired(required = false)
```

To briefly exemplify; If the `@Autowired` annotation was as follows, you could use it like the `@Lazy` annotation.

```java
public @interface Autowired {
    boolean value() default true;
}

@Autowired(false)
```